# WARN FileStreamSink: Assume no metadata directory. Error while looking for metadata directory in the path

Tags: pyspark, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

I am newbie with Pyspark, I currently have an problem when I read json file.

I installed pyspark in Ubuntu20.04 on Windows and I just read file from local
Here is my problem:

My code:

```
df = spark.read.json('Python-and-Spark-for-Big-Data-master/Spark_DataFrames/people.json')
df.show()
```

Response:

```
23/09/28 20:10:31 WARN FileStreamSink: Assume no metadata directory. Error while looking for metadata directory in the path: Python-and-Spark-for-Big-Data-master/Spark_DataFrames/people.json.
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response has invalid length
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$IpcStreams.readResponse(Client.java:1933)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:1238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:1134)

Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/ductien/learn-pyspark/spark_df_basic.ipynb Cell 3 line 1
----> 1 df = spark.read.json('Python-and-Spark-for-Big-Data-master/Spark_DataFrames/people.json')
      2 df.show()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py:418, in DataFrameReader.json(self, path, schema, primitivesAsString, prefersDecimal, allowComments, allowUnquotedFieldNames, allowSingleQuotes, allowNumericLeadingZero, allowBackslashEscapingAnyCharacter, mode, columnNameOfCorruptRecord, dateFormat, timestampFormat, multiLine, allowUnquotedControlChars, lineSep, samplingRatio, dropFieldIfAllNull, encoding, locale, pathGlobFilter, recursiveFileLookup, modifiedBefore, modifiedAfter, allowNonNumericNumbers)
    416 if type(path) == list:
    417     assert self._spark._sc._jvm is not None
--> 418     return self._df(self._jreader.json(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    419 elif isinstance(path, RDD):
    421     def func(iterator: Iterable) -> Iterable:

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py:169, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
...
: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcException: RPC response has invalid length
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$IpcStreams.readResponse(Client.java:1933)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:1238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:1134)
```

Thank you!

I have tried to find the solution for my problem but there is no one can solve it.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it ?